# Deferring all heavy computation using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript, underscore.js, nonblocking

1. Lets say I have a really heavy piece of computation, it involves two nested for loops goings over an array of size 1000*1000
2. The calculation takes about 1 minute to do.
3. I have a bunch of other stuff going on in the webpage especially user interaction. ( on-click, on-scroll, animation, etc )
4. Now I need to do the 60s calculation at some point. I can for example do:

   ```
   setTimeout TwoForLoops,0
   ```

   this will defer the function call to until all the other on-click,on-scroll,etc events are cleared.
   however as the calculation takes 1 Minute, the user might trigger some event during that time. 
   do you think if I just do the following I will prevent JavaScript from hanging. Assuming that heavyComputation
   takes about 0.06 millisecond to computate.

   ```
   # _.map is from underscore@ library, basically does a for loop
   # HeavyComputation is a slow function with lots of operations made for my app

   NonBlockMap = (x,f)-> setTimeout (->_.map x,f),0

   NonBlockHeavyComputation = (x) -> setTimeout (-> HeavyComputation(x)),0

   TwoForLoops = (ArrayOfArray) ->

      SecondLoop = (element) -> NonBlockHeavyComputation element

      FirstLoop = (array) -> NonBlockMap array, SecondLoop


      return NonBlockMap ArrayOfArray,FirstLoop
   ```

   This would essentially mean that the maximum javascript will hang for is about 0.06 millisecond but
   I am not so sure if this will work.

   WhatDo ?

Comment: You're not using `setTimeout` correctly. It takes a function as its first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code queues all million HeavyComputation continuables up front, not as it progreses.  The event loop will process each one in order before handling new user events, so you've still blocked for a minute.

You should use setImmediate though, or double-check that setTimeout of 0 does not sleep.  Nodejs (what I work in; maybe chrome too?) always sleeps 1 ms.

Consider batching the heavy computation nested loop, something like:

```
function batchedHeavyComputation( elements, iFrom, jFrom, batchSize ) {
    var i, j, numcalls = 0;
    for (i=iFrom; i<1000; i++) {
        for (j=jFrom; j<1000; j++) {
            HeavyComputation(elements[i][j])
            if (++numcalls >= batchSize) {
                setImmediate(function(){
                    var jNext = j < 999 : j+1 : 0;
                    var iNext = j < 999 ? i : i+1;
                    batchedHeavyComputation(elements, iNext, jNext, batchSize);
                });
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

batchedHeavyComputation(elements, 0, 0, 20);
```

Comment: Yeah I think what you say makes sense. Node.js/Chrome would put all million computation in the event loop altogether ! and the user event would be placed last in the queue

Comment: "Note: This method is not expected to become standard, and is only implemented by recent builds of Internet Explorer and Node.js 0.10+. It meets resistance both from Gecko (Firefox) and Webkit (Google/Apple)."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setImmediate

"This method can be used instead of the setTimeout(fn, 0) method to execute heavy operations. "